# How can i randomize the position of particles even more?

Tags: particles

I'm trying to do a Asteroid belt, as you can see in the image the first one works well (for its own size) because the asteroids have a lot more random positions that the big one, but that's the problem, in the bigger asteroid belt, i made a different particle system, based in one single asteroid, rotated (and it still works grealy) because if i add a group as particles, the groups are too notorious and i want to make this as natural as possible, is there any way to randomize even more the particles, like in the small asteroid belt i did? 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

- Attach a Voronoi or Noise Texture.  Affect the pattern of particles by selecting Influence Density TRUE.
  [image]
- The texture in the particles system

[image]

- Modify to suit your artistic goal.